# Is thread theoretically possible?

Tags: pern

In the [Dragonriders of Pern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonriders_of_Pern) series there is an extraterrestrial substance known as [Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(Pern)#Thread). This Thread is nasty stuff that is introduced to the planet of Pern by a rogue planetoid moving close enough to the planet, that Pern's gravity pulls Thread from the rogue planetoid into the atmosphere of Pern, which then falls to the ground and proceeds to eat any carbon based anything it comes into contact with. For more information see the links.

My question is, **Is a substance such as Thread theoretically or scientifically possible?**

Comment: I think this belongs more on Biology.SE?

Comment: @DVK normally I would agree with you, except this stuff originates in a fiction novel and as far as we know, is entirely fictional in-itself. Is sci-fi-theory biology material? not quite sure.

Comment: doesn't matter, there are more biology experts there and you're asking if it's **scientifically** possible.

Comment: Nooo, keep it here! We need really interesting questions like this.

Comment: @DVK I could always ask it there too..., hey thats a thought. Can two dupes excists across .se sites?

Comment: Dupes are generally not a good idea but two similar specific questions are okay

Comment: Didn't the FAQ, at least in the past, specify that questions about, "Is this stuff from a book or movie really possible?" are inappropriate here?

Comment: @Tango I went through the FAQ before I posted this for that reason, I hope I didnt miss something. I'd end up feeling pretty stupid.

Comment: @Ender: The fact that this question is *motivated* by a work of SFF is irrelevant to the actual question itself, which is about the feasibility of something under real-world science.  Thus, it belongs on a science SE site, not here.

Comment: There are lots of things on Pern that are based on realistic science, for example, Agenothree flame throwers. This is a good Pern question.

Comment: There seems to be a gread deal of disagreement wether this belongs here or not. Sorry for making waves.

Comment: @Ender - no need to be sorry. Not every question is 100% straighforward to place on specific SE site. When in doubt, you can ask on Meta

Comment: ... and just to be clear, I'm not saying it does NOT belong here, just that it belongs on Biology more due to better expertise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Thread is described as "mycorrhizoid" spores, that " that consumes organic material at a voracious rate, including crops, animals, and any humans in its path".

As such, it sounds somewhat plausible - there are indeed fungi and bacteria which eat all sorts of organics.

Comment: Self recognition is a bit of a problem for something as voracious as thread. IOW, how does thread know NOT to eat itself?  Isolating the recognition factor and figuring out how to produce it in kilogram quantities might prove much cheaper than breeding and keeping dragons.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - AFAIK, none of the lifeforms on Earth have this self-recognition problem :)  It doesn't sound intractable at all.

Comment: Also, dragons are *way* more awesome.

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me that the Thread could be a genetically engineered weapon designed to destroy life on Pern from some ancient war. After all the whole 200/400 year cycle is a very strange setup.

There's a story, The Plague Star, in the [Tuf Voyaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuf_Voyaging) compilation by George RR Martin  where Tuf finds an ancient warship that is set to cast plagues upon a planet every hundred years that would make for a similar setup when seen from the point of view of the planet's denizens.

Wether or not it's actually possible in the real world I don't know but in sci-fi in general genetic engineering seems to be accepted as more than capable of creating such a situation.

Comment: actually it is, and one book mentions this, but my questions is about its real world possibilities.

Comment: As @Ender mentions, the possibility that Thread is a manufactured/genetically engineered organism is mentioned and considered in at least one of the Pern novels, but as far as I can remember, never conclusively determined. Regardless of origin, the ~200 year cycle doesn't require any artificial design, since it's just a factor of celestial mechanics and planetary orbits. The reason for the occasional long interval of ~400 years is also explored in one of the later books.